# Detect Post Type when publish_post is ran

Tags: posts, publish

I currently have WordPress build an `XML Sitemap` everytime a `POST` or `PAGE` is `PUBLISHED` by using this Action...

```
add_action("publish_post", "create_news_sitemap");
```

I am not doing the same process but for a `News Sitemap` which has different criteria.  Such as it can only show post that are no older then 48 hours.

I have my code working but I would like to optimize it slightly.

So when `add_action("publish_post", "create_news_sitemap");` is ran, I would like to ONLY run a function is it is a Custom Post Type named `news` that is Publishing a post.

Is this something that is possible?

when the `publish_post` action is ran, can I detect which POST_TYPE is setting it into action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`publish_post` will give you a second parameter if you ask for it. Notice the fourth parameter of the `add_action` call. That is your post object.

```
function run_on_publish_wpse_100421( $postid, $post ) { 
  if ('news' == $post->post_type) 
    // your code
  }
}
add_action('publish_post','run_on_publish_wpse_100421',1,2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `publish_post` action gets the post ID as argument, pass that to [`get_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) to find out what type of post it is:

```
function create_news_sitemap( $post_id ){
    $type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    if( 'news' == $type ){
        // do something
    }
}
add_action("publish_post", "create_news_sitemap");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for the post type, you can also use `publish_{post_type }`.   In your case `publish_news`

```
function run_on_publish_wpse_100421( $postid, $post ) { 
    // your code
}
add_action('publish_news','run_on_publish_wpse_100421',1,2);
```

Comment: Good call, i'm aware of this but it appears back in 2013 I wasn't...this is a good method =) +1